# mouse hover to Button card shadow effect should display

Tags: html, css

Hi in my code I have added hover effect for a card. (Ex) if the user hovers to the card. card shadow effect and Add To Cart button will display. But when user mouse hovers to the button I have to display the card shadow effect. so please tell me how to do it. here I have mentioned my Html code and its CSS.

```css
/* overallCart */
.overallCart{
  min-height: 272.5px;
}

/* card */
.card5-diagonal {
  border-color: transparent;
  width: 170px;
  height: 247.5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* card overeffect */
.card5-diagonal:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
/* image*/
.card5-image {
  width: 144px;
  height: 122px;
  margin-right: 13px;
  margin-left: 13px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/* Over Button space*/
.button-space {
  display: none;
}
/* Over Button hover effect */
.overallCart:hover .button-space {
  display: block;
}
/* Button */
.addtocart-btn {
  min-width: 170px;
  max-width: 170px;
  min-height: 25px;
  max-height: 25px;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: RR;
  font-size: 12px;
  outline: none;
  border: #212121;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 
 <div class="overallCart">
  <div class="card card5-diagonal">

    <!-- Image Start -->
    <img class="card5-image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcT05KW2maV5ZFB9ipDuXxFCg55Rwb6Grx3iiURgsOFMpWwWX27u" />
    <!-- Image End -->
 
  </div>
  <!-- Footer Start -->
  <div class="btn-space">
    <span class="button-space ">
      <button type="button" class="addtocart-btn ">ADD TO CART </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <!-- Footer End -->
</div>
```

Comment: what you want us to do??.. show add to cart button only when you hover on the card?

Comment: @XenioGracias mouse hover to Add to cart button card shadow effect should display.

Comment: all the `card` . will inside `overallCart`?

Comment: this css `.card5-diagonal` should highlight.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by jQuery

```
$('.addtocart-btn,.card5-diagonal').hover(function(){
    $('.card5-diagonal').css('box-shadow','0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)');
}, function(){
    $('.card5-diagonal').css('box-shadow','inherit');
});
```

and remove this from CSS.

```
/* card overeffect */
.card5-diagonal:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

DEMO
https://jsfiddle.net/Ls9eju6y/

Comment: Actually the card was in loop so if i mouse hover to one card all card gets highlighted.

Comment: Is there any possible to achive by using CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn-space").hover(function () {
        $(this).prev().css("box-shadow", "0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)");
    }, function () {
        $(this).prev().css("box-shadow", "");
    });
});
```

```css
.overallCart {
    min-height: 272.5px;
    width: 25%;
}
        
.card5-diagonal {
    border-color: transparent;
    width: 170px;
    height: 247.5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card5-diagonal:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    width: 100%;
}

.card5-image {
    width: 144px;
    height: 122px;
    margin-right: 13px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.button-space {
    display: none;
}

.overallCart:hover .button-space {
    display: block;
}
.addtocart-btn {
    min-width: 170px;
    /* max-width: 170px; */
    min-height: 25px;
    max-height: 25px;
    background-color: #212121;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: RR;
    font-size: 12px;
    outline: none;
    border: #212121;
    width: 100%;
}
.card {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<div class="overallCart">
    <div class="card card5-diagonal">
        <img class="card5-image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcT05KW2maV5ZFB9ipDuXxFCg55Rwb6Grx3iiURgsOFMpWwWX27u" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-space">
        <span class="button-space ">
            <button type="button" class="addtocart-btn ">ADD TO CART </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my case i have to replace instant of a to b and b to a it was not working.

Comment: @Sudharsan Venkatraj  check edit code,jQuery work with .prev()  so if you mouse hover to one card only one card gets highlighted

Answer (score 0):

check this let me know if you want to change anything. thanks

```css
/* overallCart */

.overallCart {
  min-height: 272.5px;
  width: 25%;
}


/* card */

.card5-diagonal {
  border-color: transparent;
  width: 170px;
  height: 247.5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* card overeffect */

.card5-diagonal:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  width: 100%;
}


/* image*/

.card5-image {
  width: 144px;
  height: 122px;
  margin-right: 13px;
  margin-left: 13px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}


/* Over Button space*/

.button-space {
  display: none;
}


/* Over Button hover effect */

.overallCart:hover .button-space {
  display: block;
}


/* Button */

.addtocart-btn {
  min-width: 170px;
  /* max-width: 170px; */
  min-height: 25px;
  max-height: 25px;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: RR;
  font-size: 12px;
  outline: none;
  border: #212121;
  width: 100%;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="overallCart">
  <div class="card card5-diagonal">

    <!-- Image Start -->
    <img class="card5-image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcT05KW2maV5ZFB9ipDuXxFCg55Rwb6Grx3iiURgsOFMpWwWX27u" />
    <!-- Image End -->

  </div>
  <!-- Footer Start -->
  <div class="btn-space">
    <span class="button-space ">
      <button type="button" class="addtocart-btn ">ADD TO CART </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <!-- Footer End -->
</div>
```